# Is there a way to automate the creation of Docker Image?

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I needed to create a Docker image of a Springboot application and I achieved that by creating a Dockerfile and building it into an image. Then, I used "docker run" to bring up a container. This container is used for all the activities for which my application was written.

My problem, however, is that the JAR file that I have used needs constant changes and that requires me to rebuild the Docker image everytime. Furthermore, I need to take the contents of the earlier running Docker container and transfer it into a container created from the newly built image.

I know this whole process can be written as a Shell script and exected every time I have changes on my JAR file. But, is there any tool I can use to somehow automate it in a simple manner?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
WORKDIR /app 
ADD ./SuperApi ./SuperApi 
ADD ./config ./config 
ADD ./Resources ./Resources 
EXPOSE 8000 
CMD java -jar SuperApi/SomeName.jar --spring.config.location=SuperApi/application.properties
```

Comment: Please share the Dockerfile. It seems that you have a Dockerfile more suitable for production, not for continuous development.

Comment: Here's the Dockerfile contents:

`FROM java:8
WORKDIR /app
ADD ./SuperApi ./SuperApi
ADD ./config ./config
ADD ./Resources ./Resources
EXPOSE 8000
CMD java -jar SuperApi/SomeName.jar -- spring.config.location=SuperApi/application.properties`

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the Dockerfile there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a JAR file that you need to copy into an otherwise static Docker image, you can use a bind mount to save needing to rebuild repeatedly. This allows for directories to be shared from the host into the container.

Say your project directory (the build location where the JAR file is located) on the host machine is `/home/vishwas/projects/my_project`, and you need to have the contents placed at `/opt/my_project` inside the container. When starting the container from the command line, use the `-v` flag:

```
docker run -v /home/vishwas/projects/my_project:/opt/my_project [...]
```

Changes made to files under `/home/vishwas/projects/my_project` locally will be visible immediately inside the container<sup>1</sup>, so no need to rebuild (and probably no need to restart) the container.

If using docker-compose, this can be expressed using a `volumes` stanza under the services listing for that container:

```
volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: /home/vishwas/projects/my_project
      target: /opt/my_project
```

This works for development, but later on, it's likely you'll want to bundle the JAR file into the image instead of sharing from the host system (so it can be placed into production). When that time comes, just re-build the image and add a `COPY` directive to the Dockerfile:

```
COPY /home/vishwas/projects/my_project  /opt/my_project
```

---

<sub>1: Worth noting that it will default to read/write, so the container will also be able to modify your project files. To mount as read-only, use: `docker run -v /home/vishwas/projects/my_project:/opt/my_project:ro`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

You can build and start containers with a single command using compose.